# Unity transform.Translate(Vector3.forward); doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am learning through "Create With Code" tutorial from Unity. Here they say, that I can use

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
```

command to move object by `Z` coordination. But it doesn't work.

My error if you need it:

> 'Vector3' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector3' and 'System.Numerics.Vector3' [Assembly-CSharp].

Comment: So make it a specific reference to the right one?

Comment: Can you please add your code, it will be easier to understand why is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is an ambiguous reference, which means the type `Vector3` exists in 2 different namespace, those being `UnityEngine` and `System.Numerics`.

There are 3 ways to resolve this issue:

1. Explicitly use the namespace you want with `UnityEngine.Vector3.forward`
2. Create an alias to resolve the conflict with `using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3`. This will create an alias called `Vector3` which will reference the type you want.
3. Remove the conflicting namespace, if possible. If you're not using the `System.Numerics` namespace, you can simply remove it. Otherwise, please use one of the options above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do

```
public float speed = 10f; 

private void Update() {
    transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Or if you want to add a key input you can do

```
public float speed = 10f; 

private void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.YourKey) { // Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) for example and '//' means comment so this won't be included in your code
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: And also your script needs to be in the object you want to move if this helps.

Comment: you shouldn't use `transform.forward` in that case ... by default `Translate` already acts within the local space of the given transform so `transform.forward` (which is a world space vector) would be wrong ... you want `Vector3.forward`